# MODIS MOD13Q1 data time coverage problem

Tags: modis

I downloaded modis MOD13Q1 data as shown below, which is 250m NDVI data every 16 days. But I'm not sure about the time range of this data. For example, 2014-01-17-NDVI data, does it cover the period from 2014-01-17 to 2014-02-01? Or 2014-01-02 to 2014-01-17 time period?[image]

Comment: Where did you get those TIFF files from? This data is originally supplied as HDF with two dates encoded in the file name - acquisition date and production date. How did your TIFF files get their names? https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/missions-and-measurements/products/MOD13Q1#product-information

Comment: I don't know why you tagged with "R" when there's no R code (maybe you downloaded it via an R package, in which case please edit the Q and give details). I've removed the tag and tagged it with "modis" which might get someone who can give a definitive answer.